# Determining which integer is closest to the kth root of n without using floating point arithmetic?

Tags: algorithm, math, integer

Suppose that I want to compute <sup>k</sup>√n rounded to the nearest integer, where n and k are nonnegative integers. Using binary search, I can find an integer a such that

> a<sup>k</sup> ≤ n < (a+1)<sup>k</sup>.

This means that either a or a+1 is the kth root of n rounded to the nearest integer. However, I'm not sure how to determine which one it is without doing some calculations that involve floating-point arithmetic.

Given the values of a, n, and k, is there a way to determine the kth root of n rounded to the nearest integer without doing any floating-point calculations?

Thanks!

Comment: A naive approach would be to compute a^k and (a+1)^k, and compute which is closer to n, all integer maths.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth- that approach doesn't necessarily work. Try using this to compute the cube root of 16, which is about 2.51. If you compute 2^3 you get 8 and if you compute 3^3 you get 27. Although 27 is further from 16 than 8, 3 is the correct answer.

Comment: Ah I see, I misinterpreted what you were looking for ;)

Comment: Good example. Let's solve it. 2.5^3 - 16 is positive if and only if 5^3 - 16*2^3 is positive. Test that on my integer calculator—it says it's negative—which means 2.5 is smaller than the root, ie. the root is closer to 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2<sup>k</sup>a<sup>k</sup> < 2<sup>k</sup>n < (2a+1)<sup>k</sup> → (dividing by 2<sup>k</sup>) a<sup>k</sup> < n < (a+0.5)<sup>k</sup> → (taking the kth root) a < <sup>k</sup>√n < a+0.5, so the kth root of  n is closer to `a` than to `a+1`. Note that the edge case will not occur; the kth root of an integer can not be an integer plus 0.5 (a+0.5) as the kth roots of n which are not kth powers are irrational and if n were a perfect kth power, then the kth root would be an integer.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but how does this help determine whether the answer is a or a + 1?

Comment: @templatetypedef If the value of `a` satisfies the criteria, then it is the closest integer. If a<sup>k</sup> < n < (a+0.5)<sup>k</sup>, then the kth root of n is between a and a+0.5, so `a` must be the closer one.

Comment: Should there be a 2^k term in front of the n in that second inequality?

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes; fixed that.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: `n < 2^k(2a+1)^k` should be `2^k n < (2a+1)^k`, no?

Comment: @unutbu Sigh. Fixed that.

Comment: +1 Good solution.  May be worth formatting this onto separate lines to make it easier to read, though.

Comment: @RamchandraApte: `2^k (2a+1)^k` should just be `(2a+1)^k`, yes? (Good answer by the way).

Comment: @unutbu Argh; it's all because of my sleepiness and cold.

Comment: @RamchandraApte though a nice mathematical solution but writing it in a program might cause overflow for larger value example n=2^64 then when calculating 64th root then 2^k*n used in inequality is 2^64*2^64 which is enormous.

Answer (score 3):

The answers by [Ramchandra Apte](//stackoverflow.com/a/20730616) and [Lazarus](//stackoverflow.com/a/20730856) both contain what seems to be the essence of the correct answer, but both are also (at least to me) a bit hard to follow.  Let me try to explain the trick they seem to be getting at, as I understand it, a bit more clearly:

The basic idea is that, to find out whether *a* or *a*+1 is closer to <sup>*k*</sup>√*n*, we need to test whether <sup>*k*</sup>√*n* < *a*+½.

To get rid of the ½, we can simply multiply both sides of this inequality by 2, giving 2·<sup>*k*</sup>√*n* < 2*a*+1, and by raising both sides to the *k*-th power (and assuming they're both positive) we get the equivalent inequality 2<sup>*k*</sup>·*n* < (2*a*+1)<sup>*k*</sup>.  So, at least as long as 2<sup>*k*</sup>·*n* = *n* ≪ *k* does not overflow, we can simply compare it with (2*a*+1)<sup>*k*</sup> to obtain the answer.

In fact, we could simply compute *b* = ⌊ <sup>*k*</sup>√(2<sup>*k*</sup>·*n*) ⌋ to begin with.  If *b* is even, then the closest integer to <sup>*k*</sup>√*n* is *b* / 2; if *b* is odd, it is (*b* + 1) / 2.  Indeed, we can combine the two cases and say that the closest integer to <sup>*k*</sup>√*n* is ⌊ (*b*+1) / 2 ⌋, or, in pseudo-C:

```c
int round_root( int k, int n ) {
    int b = floor_root( k, n << k );
    return (b + 1) / 2;
}
```

---

Ps. An alternative approach could be to compute an approximation (*a*+½)<sup>*k*</sup> directly using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) as
(*a*+½)<sup>*k*</sup>
= ∑<sub>*i*=0..*k*</sub> (*k* choose *i*) *a*<sup>*k*−*i*</sup> / 2<sup>*i*</sup>
≈ *a*<sup>*k*</sup>
+ *k*·*a*<sup>*k*−1</sup> / 2 + ... and compare it directly with *n*.  However, at least naïvely, summing all the terms of the binomial expansion would still require keeping track of *k* extra bits of precision (or at least *k*−1; I believe the last term can be safely neglected), so it may not gain much over the method suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want to use this algorithm on an FPGA/CPLD, or a processor with limited resources, since your approach reminds me of CORDIC. Hence, I will give a solution with that in mind.

When you reach `a^k ≤ n < (a+1)^k`, it means that floor of x=root(n,k) is 'a'. In other words, x = a + f, where `0=<f<0.5`. Thus, multiplying the equation by 2, you will have `2x=2a+2f`. It basically means that `floor(2x) = 2a` (since 2f<1). Now, `x = √n (kth root)`, thus `2x = k√((2^k)*n) (kth root)`. So, just shift n by k bits to left, then calculate its kth root with your algorithm. If its lower bound was exactly 2 times kth root of n, then kth root of n is a, otherwise it is a+1.

Assuming you have a function that gives you the lower bound of the kth root of n (rootk(n)), the final result, using binary operators and with C notations, would be:

closestint = a + ((rootk(n) << 1) == rootk(n>>k) );

Answer (score 0):

Compute the cube of `(a + 0.5)*10` (or `10a + 5` - no floating point arithmetic), then divide it by `1000`.

Then check on which side the number is.

The idea of multiplying by 10 is to shift the decimal place one position to the right. Then we divide by 1000 because we multiplied by 10 3 times because of the cubing.

**For example:**

```
Input: 16

a = 2
a+1 = 3

a^3 = 8
(a+1)^3 = 27

10a + 5 = 25

25^3 = 15625

floor(15625 / 1000) = 15

16 > 15, thus 3 is closer.
```

It would also work to, as [Oli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oli-charlesworth) pointed out, compute the cube of `(a + 0.5)*2` (or `2a + 1`), then divide it by `8`.

**For example:**

```
2a + 1 = 5

5^3 = 125

floor(125 / 8) = 15

16 > 15, thus 3 is closer.
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth To shift the decimal place one to the right.

Comment: I guess what I mean is, 10 seems like a magic number here; decimal isn't intrinsic to any of the maths going on.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It needs to be 10, otherwise `(a + 0.5)*whatever` won't necessarily be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newton's method to find *a*; it works perfectly well with integers, and is faster than binary search. Then compute *a<sup>k</sup>* and (*a*+1)<sup>*k*</sup> using the square-and-multiply powering algorithm. Here's some code, in Scheme because I happened to have that [handy](http://programmingpraxis.com/contents/standard-prelude/):

```
(define (iroot k n) ; largest integer x such that x ^ k <= n
  (let ((k-1 (- k 1)))
    (let loop ((u n) (s (+ n 1)))
      (if (<= s u) s
        (loop (quotient (+ (* k-1 u) (quotient n (expt u k-1))) k) u)))))

(define (ipow b e) ; b^e
  (if (= e 0) 1
    (let loop ((s b) (i e) (a 1)) ; a * s^i = b^e
      (let ((a (if (odd? i) (* a s) a)) (i (quotient i 2)))
        (if (zero? i) a (loop (* s s) i a))))))
```

To determine which of *a<sup>k</sup>* and (*a*+1)<sup>*k*</sup> is closer to the root, you could use the powering algorithm to compute (*a* + <sup>1</sup>/<sub>2</sub>)<sup>*k*</sup> — it's an exact calculation that the square-and-multiply operation can perform — then compare the result to *n* and determine which side is closer.

Comment: I don't think that choosing which of a^n and (a+1)^n will tell the correct answer in all cases. See my comment on the question for a counterexample.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Sorry. Please see the last paragraph that I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: -**

Sorry of misunderstanding the problem. Here is a possible solution of original question :-

Use newtons approximation theorem : -

```
here = means (approximately = )

f(b+a) = f(b) + a*f'(b)

 a -> 0

f(x) = x^k

f'(x) = k*x^(k-1)

hence using above equation

f(a+0.5) = a^k + 1/2*k*a^(k-1);



need to check    n < f(a+0.5)  

                 n < a^k + 1/2*k*a^(k-1)

rearranging      (n-a^k)*2 < k*a^(k-1)
```

**Note:** you can use binomial theorem to get more precision.

Comment: I think you might have misread my question. I'm aware I can use binary search to find a close value, but if the root is between two integers I don't know how to round to the nearest one. Does your answer address how to handle this?

Comment: @templatetypedef okay sorry i misread it, what sort of precision you need ?

Answer (score 0):

Think. Ideally, you'd do one more step of binary search, to see which side of a+½ the root lies. That is, test the inequality

> (a+0.5)<sup>k</sup> < n

But the left hand side is difficult to compute precisely (floating point issues). So write down an equivalent inequality in which all the terms are integers:

> (2a+1)<sup>k</sup> < 2<sup>k</sup> n

Done.

Comment: same as  RamchandraApte but my question is will it not cause overflow for larger values of n for example i want for n = 2^40 the 40th root then 2^k*n = 2^80 causes overflow when the answer the is way below size of long which is 2

Comment: the obvious question is that can we get good precision without overflow and floating point calculations?